# Scripts - Carregar todos ou fracionar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma página com vários elementos estáticos, estes que, carregam elementos dinâmicos, basicamente todos em `body` distribuídos em `divs`, via *Ajax*.

Esses elementos dinâmicos utilizam várias funções, relativamente ligadas a cada um deles.

Quando então carrego elemento X, preciso das funções X. Quando carrego elemento Y, as funções Y.

---

As dúvidas:

- É "correto" carregar parte do script (que seriam cada funções referentes ao elemento carregado) somente quando carregar tal elemento? (pois os scripts ficariam dentro das divs)
- Ou o ideal seria um script com todas funções, carregando em `head`? (mas isso iria carregar muita função desnecessária)
- Existe um "autoload" ou alguma forma dinâmica de carregamento de scripts?

Comment: Como forma de estudo eu recomendaria que você fizesse das duas formas e testasse o resultado.

Comment: Então, funcionou normal, nos 2 casos... Mas scripts no meio do conteúdo, estaria certo? Fica estranho, mas funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu não tenho um ambiente de testes para validar essa técnica, mas ela existe e inclusive é descrita [nesse artigo do próprio Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/link-rel-preload). *Mas como estou dizendo cabe vc testar para avaliar o resultado...*

O que vamos fazer é um `preload` do `script`. Desse forma vc pode ter um script principal que vai carregar com prioridade, e no `script` `href="carrega-depois.js"` vc faz o `preload` para ele carregar depois que a primeira renderização estiver completa.

> O valor **`preload`** do atributo `rel` do elemento `<link>` permite que você escreva solicitações de busca declarativas em seu elemento `<head>` do HTML, **especificando recursos que suas páginas vão precisar logo após o carregamento**.

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

O valor do atributo `rel="preload"` pode ser aplicado a vários formatos de arquivo, incluindo CSS, JS, fontes, imagens e muito mais. Você deve definir o atributo correspondente como dependendo do tipo de arquivo. Para CSS, o valor deve ser `as="style"` e para JavaScript `as="script"`. [Artigo com mais detalhes](https://alligator.io/html/preload-prefetch/)

```
<link rel="preload" href="carrega-depois.js" as="script">

<script>
  // Mais tarde, depois de alguma condição ter sido atendida, nós executamos o pré-carregado 
  // JavaScript inserindo uma tag <script> no DOM.
  var usedLaterScript = document.createElement('script');
  usedLaterScript.src = 'carrega-depois.js';
  document.body.appendChild(usedLaterScript)
</script>
```

Esse é um artigo bem completo sobre `preload` e `prefetch` que pode te ajudar, recomendo que leia: https://medium.com/reloading/preload-prefetch-and-priorities-in-chrome-776165961bbf

Answer (score 0):

Olá.
Eu costumo minificar todos os meus scripts em um único arquivo javascript, isso agiliza na hora de fazer o Load e melhora o desempenho da página.
Recomendo fazer dessa forma.
Caso queira carregar os scripts "dinamicamente", segue abaixo um exemplo de função que já utilizei em um projeto para fazer o que você está precisando.

```
function dynamicallyLoadScript(url, callback) {
        // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
        var head = document.head;
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = url;

        // Then bind the event to the callback function.
        // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
        script.onreadystatechange = callback;
        script.onload = callback;

        // Fire the loading
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
```

No exemplo que postei, como primeiro parâmetro, você irá passar a URL do arquivo que deseja carregar, e no segundo parâmetro, alguma função callback para ser executada assim que o arquivo for carregado caso deseje.

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços.