# Vídeo em site não travar

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Estamos desenvolvendo um site onde o banner será um vídeo. Através do Pixabay, encontramos um vídeo que é perfeito para o negócio de nosso cliente. O problema é que o vídeo está travando quando subimos para o servidor. Tem algum meio de impedir esse travamento? Veja abaixo o código:

```
<style>
.bg_video{
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    z-index: -1000;
    background-size: cover; 
}
</style>

<div id="banner">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video autoplay loop poster="img/slides/1.jpg" class="bg_video img-responsive">
      <source src="video/business.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Veja abaixo as configurações do vídeo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O primeiro passo é tentar diminuir o peso desse vídeo, aqui tem algumas técnicas que podem te ajudar, **leia o texto!** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262660/otimizar-v%C3%ADdeo-em-html-5/, leia aqui também! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267503/qual-o-tamanho-ideal-para-um-v%C3%ADdeo-mp4-no-fundo-da-p%C3%A1gina/267537#267537 Depois seria interessante fazer uns testes com o `rel="preload"` leia aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/364931/scripts-carregar-todos-ou-fracionar/ outra pergunta que ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269556/o-que-%C3%A9-rel-preload

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, segui as dicas passadas pelo Hugocsl.

Comment: Fox posso votar para fechar como duplicada? Se a outra resposta ajudou seria melhor redirecionar essa para a outra....

Comment: Oi Hugo. Pode sim. Obrigado :D